# Как узнать имя пользователя и домен в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ли какой-то нормальный способ узнать имя пользователя и домен? Есть локальная сеть, ввиду разных причин, сервер не в домене. Если в домене - то можно через Windows-авторизацию. Нужно это, чтобы не мучить пользователей-читателей авторизацией. Ниже приведен код, который после 2-3х нажатий согласен - даёт имена под IE.

```
<input type='text' id='Edit1' value='test' />
<input type='text' id='Edit2' value='test' />

<script>
  function doEvent() {
    var net = new ActiveXObject("wscript.network");
    Edit1.value = net.UserName;
    Edit2.value = net.UserDomain;
  }
  window.setTimeout("doEvent()", 100);
</script>
```

Есть ли какой более нормальный способ узнать эту информацию?

Comment: *ONMOUSEOVER* — ? А ничего, что нажатие это `onclick`?

Comment: @Yuri Скачал с https://javascript.ru/forum/misc/4094-tekushhee-imya-polzovatelya-i-domen.html как есть, вообще правильно так: `window.setTimeout("doEvent()",100);`

Comment: Какие страшные вещи вы говорите :)

Comment: @Yuri Вы код мне поменали так, что теперь сложно повторить результат. У меня кнопка выполнить код не даёт тот результат который я получаю локально. С системными вызовами так нельзя делать.